# Why I am unable to route to another module by Lazyloading?

Tags: angular, typescript

**When I try http://localhost:4200/admin I always get at http://localhost:4200/student**

**I use lazyloading to route to two different modules but I am unable to get to admin part**

*My app-routing.module.ts code*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:"",
    redirectTo:"student",
    pathMatch:"full"
  },
  {
    path:"student",
    loadChildren : ()=> import("./student/student.module").then(m=> m.StudentModule)
  },
  {
    path:"admin",
    loadChildren : ()=> import("./admin/admin.module").then(n => n.AdminModule)
  },
  {
    path:'**',
    component:ErrorComponent
  }
  
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**Here I use two LazyLoading one for Student and other for Admin But Admin doesn't work**

*my admin-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { DashbordComponent } from '../student/dashbord/dashbord.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component:DashbordComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

*my student-routing.module.ts*

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { ChangepasswordComponent } from './changepassword/changepassword.component';
import { DashbordComponent } from './dashbord/dashbord.component';
import { EditprofileComponent } from './editprofile/editprofile.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ViewprofileComponent } from './viewprofile/viewprofile.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:"",
    component:LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path:"dashbord",
    component:DashbordComponent
  },
  {
    path:"viewprofile",
    component:ViewprofileComponent
  },
  {
    path:"editprofile",
    component:EditprofileComponent
  },
  {
    path:'changepassword',
    component:ChangepasswordComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class StudentRoutingModule { }
```

**Whenever I try to get admin I was unable. Plz help . Thanks**

Comment: Please post any error message or console message. That will help others to analyze the content

Comment: Where I use console message

Comment: I would assume it's because of your imports. Your `admin` routing is importing `DashbordComponent` from `/student/dashbord/`. Perhaps you didn't declare the component in your `AdminModule`?

Comment: ✔️ Thanks bro that is the error thanks